# Cannot delete node in LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm having a problem where I can't remove a node from a linkedlist. My problem has an alternative purpose, but I've narrowed down the issue to the inability to delete the previous node.

```
void deleteNodes(LN<T>*& l) {

    if (l == nullptr) return;
    LN<T> *temp = nullptr;

    for (LN<T> *current = l->next, *previous = l; current != nullptr && previous != nullptr; previous = current, current = current->next) {
        delete previous;
    }
}
```

Trying to delete the previous node results in a program crash error/infinite loop.

New update: If I remove the "previous = current" and only delete previous one time I get an infinite loop.

Comment: My bad, chose the wrong tag

Comment: Think about the case where `current == nullptr` and `previous` is not. What will happen `delete previous` executes?

Comment: But I thought the for loop stops right before the nullptr so previous is never set equal to nullptr?

Comment: What does the destructor for `LN<T>` do ?  How does it handle the `next` pointer?

Comment: It looks as if this code deletes the last node in the list (was that your intention?), then leaves a dangling pointer which is sure to case trouble later.

Comment: I wanted it to delete every single node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use everything in for loop

You can do that using simple code structure. Just try this way, its may be because your for loop given in the code.

```
void deleteNodes(LN<T>*& l) {

if (l == nullptr) return;
LN<T> *temp = nullptr;

*previous = l; 

for (LN<T> *current = l->next; current != nullptr; current = current->next){

  if(previous != nullptr){  
    previous->next=nullptr;
    delete previous;
    previous = current;


  }

   else
     break;
}

    previous->next=nullptr;
    delete previous;
}
```

Comment: My program still crashes with this code. Same issue, too. I added std::cout to check it.

Comment: I think you have to set its next pointer to NULL before the node get deleted. I have updated code please try that way also.